# Use php variable set by jQuery $.post method

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a php variable $entrymode which will set to addentry or editentry when user press respective add or edit button..

To achieve this I have used $.post method where I'm sending the value to other php page and then setting the variable there.

Now until this part everything is fine.Now I want to use that variable in the page from where i sent the request

Like

```
If ($entrymode == $addentry){
    //do this
}else{
   //do this
}
```

How to achieve this...

```
            value = 'add'
            $.post('entrymode.php', {value: value}, function(data){
                $('#add_name1').html(data);
            });



<?php
include_once('common.php');
global $flag;
if(isset($_POST['value']) ){
    $flag= $_POST['value'];
}
switch($flag){
    case "add":
        $entrymode = $addentry;
        break;
    case "edit":
        $entrymode = $editentry;
        break;
}
echo $entrymode;
```

?>

Comment: `$_POST['myVariable']` ?

Comment: Use ajax and also share all related  code?

Comment: So I have to use the $_Post method to get the variable back from the other page? Like $_POST['entrymode']?

Comment: if you send like `$.post('bla.php', {entrymode:'truc'});` yes

Comment: I guess you should try yourself, you didn't share anything so I don't know your code

Comment: @macbooc ihave shared the code

Answer (score 0):

Like MacBoonc said, you frist get the variable sent using PHP's _POST:

```
$myVar = $_POST['myVariable'];
```

then your thing. after that you can send the var as a JSON response:

```
exit(json_encode($myVar));
```

But it is recommended to send an array as JSON format back to your page in order to be able to get more information from the page you posted your ajax to, for example success or error message.
this is how i'd do this:

```
var yourVar1 = "something";
var yourVar2 = "something";
var yourVar3 = "something";
var action = "your-script.php";    
        var form = {
            'data1' : yourVar1,
            'data2' : yourVar2,
            'data3' : yourVar3          
            };          
        $.post(action, form, function(data){
                if (data.status == "ok"){
                  var yourReturedVar = data.myVar;
             }

    },'json');
```

and your php:

```
$myVar = $_POST['myVariable'];
$response = array();
$response['status'] = "error";
//do your thing here
 //if iour code does what is supose to do then
$response['myVar'] = $myVar;
$response['status'] = "ok";
//send your data back as JSON
exit(json_encode($response));
```

please ask if you need more details.

Comment: as i haev shown in the code i have used  $flag= $_POST['value']  this then i have set entrymode..now i want that entrymode back to the original page with set to either add or eidt...if i use session it remain constat for either add or edit...if i use $flag= $_POST['value'] this it says undifined value..with session it changes only if the page is refreshed but i dont want to do that

Comment: just like i told you. send it back as a json. and there you can do what you want with it

Comment: @ Leonida-Alexandru Diaconu u mean I have to send the response to the original page again using $.post? if so how can I use the already set php varibale $entrymode in Jq var yourVar1 = "something"; ???

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post('entrymode.php', {value: value}, function(data){
     if(data == 'A') // you can't use php variable anymore
     {
         //do some stuff
     }
     elseif(data == 'E')
     {
          // do other stuff
     }
});
```

you can't use your PHP static variable anymore since your call is asynchrone so it happen after the page is sent. but you can apply them at the load of the page like

```
$.post('entrymode.php', {value: value}, function(data){
         if(data == <?= $addentry ?>) // you can't use php variable anymore
         {
             //do some stuff
         }
         elseif(data == <?= $editentry ?>)
         {
              // do other stuff
         }
    });
```

Comment: those to are static variables with 'A' and 'E' asigned to them..on add button click i will set entrymode as addentry and then later i'll check if($entrymode == $addentry) which will be if(A==A)..If i echo $entrymode in the switch case page it'll change on button click but if iget it back by session then it changes only on page refresh

Comment: well..i'm sorry but what u r doing is in the page where request has been sent..here i'm successfully set my entrymode depending on the button click. but what i want is use that already set entrymode varible to the page from where the request has been sent..may be i'm not currecly illustrating my problem

Comment: then in the callback you should test your variable and do some stuff with it, but you can't do that in PHP anymore, you have to do this in js, or again i don't understand what you are asking exactly

Comment: i have two page 1 & 2 when user click some button on page 1 request will sent to page 2 using jquery and will set php variable.now the variable set in page2 i want it back on page 1 to use it for conditional statements..now i dont know how to get that varibale 
to page1 from page2.. hope i'm making it clear this time

Comment: yeah then you have to manipulate javascript i'll change my anwser

Comment: that mean i can work with variable only in js and not in php?

Comment: if you are doing asynchronicous call, no you can't use php anymore

Comment: a link to make a synchronous call so i can use it in php?

Comment: then you'll change the page or reloade the same one, but yeah in that way you can